# How to delete pfx certificate using .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate, pfx

I have created code to delete pfx certificate is given below,

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(
                    StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine
                );

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                            X509Certificate2Collection collection =
                                (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

                            X509Certificate2Collection fcollection =
                                (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(
                                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                    "CN=AWS IoT Certificate", false
                                );


                            foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in fcollection)
                            {
                                byte[] rawdata = x509.RawData;
                                Console.WriteLine(
                                    "Friendly Name: {0}{1}",
                                    x509.FriendlyName, Environment.NewLine
                                );
                                Console.WriteLine(
                                    "Simple Name: {0}{1}",
                                    x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true),
                                    Environment.NewLine
                                );
                                store.Remove(x509);
                                Console.WriteLine(
                                    "X509Certificate2 for localhost removed."
                                );
                            }
                            store.Close();
```

But in the fcollection variable, didn't get certificate collection with subject name.
Here =>

```
X509Certificate2Collection fcollection =
                                    (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(
                                        X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                        "CN=AWS IoT Certificate", false
                                    );
```

How to get certificate collection. collection count getting zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X509FindType.FindBySubjectName` expects a subject name without RDN attribute: `"CN=AWS IoT Certificate" -> "AWS IoT Certificate"`. And make sure if certificate is indeed in the store.

In addition:

```
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
```

you are opening store in read-only mode. You can't modify the store using this flag.

Comment: Thank you. it is worked. Also i have changed with the code store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);